# How can I pause the game?

Tags: resident-evil-6

I have just started playing the game (about an hour in) and I don't seem to be able to pause it. The start button is usually pause but it does nothing. I can press select to bring up the phone menu but the game appears to carry on (I haven't actually tested this is a battle scenario yet though)

I am wondering if maybe this is something to do with the fact I selected to play in PSN network? The thing is though, I selected private and have not invited anybody so I have no chance of another human joining me. If this is because of network mode, can I turn it off mid-game?

So far I am just assuming... maybe you just can't pause RE6? (I hope this is not the case though)

Comment: What do you need pause for?

Comment: Are you being serious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you turn on online mode, then you cannot pause the game. If you still play alone but online mode is turned on you still cannot pause the game. Before starting the game, just turn off all the online possibilities then you can pause game by pressing start.

Comment: I finally completed my first chapter and was able to quit and continue again in offline mode, so I can confirm that this is correct - you can pause with the start button in offline mode